How to Properly Format Multi-Line Logs with pino-pretty in a Node.js Application
I am currently working on a logging service in a Node.js application using pino and pino-pretty for better readability. However, I am facing an issue with multi-line log messages where escape characters (like \n) are not being properly formatted into new lines in the console output.
Current Configuration:
import pino from 'pino';

export class LoggerService {
  private readonly logger = pino({
    formatters: {
      bindings: (bindings) => ({
        pid: bindings.pid,
        hostname: bindings.hostname,
      }),
    },
    transport: {
      target: 'pino-pretty',
      options: {
        colorize: true,
      },
    },
    timestamp: pino.stdTimeFunctions.isoTime,
    redact: ['user.email', 'user.password', 'user.hash'],
  });

  async log(message: string, context?: string) {
    this.logger.info({message, context });
  }

  async error(message: string, context?: string) {
    this.logger.error({ message, context });
  }

  // Additional methods...
}

Example:
this.logger.error(error.message,'UserService.findAllByFilter')

i get:
[16:20:29.604] ERROR (20408):
    message: "\nInvalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:\n\n{\n  where: {\n    banned: false\n  },\n  select: {\n?   id?: true,\n?   email?: true,\n?   profileUrl?: true,\n?   avatar?: true,\n?   firstName?: true,\n?   lastName?: true,\n?   hash?: true,\n?   banned?: true,\n?   confirmed?: true,\n?   redirectUrl?: true,\n?   sessions?: true,\n?   teacherProfile?: true,\n?   studentProfile?: true,\n?   adminProfile?: true,\n?   _count?: true\n  },\n  skip: 0,\n  take: 10\n}\n\nThe `select` statement for type User needs at least one truthy value."
    context: "UserService.findAllByFilter"

As you see, formatting just broke down.
P.S. for production I'm going to push all logs to BetterStack

After adding:
messageKey: 'message'

to options in transport, everything is now fine.
Final code:
private readonly logger = pino({
    formatters: {
      bindings: (bindings) => {
        return {
          pid: bindings.pid,
          hostname: bindings.hostname,
        };
      },
    },
    transport: {
      target: 'pino-pretty',
      options: {
        colorize: true,
        messageKey: 'message',
      },
    },
    timestamp: pino.stdTimeFunctions.isoTime,
    redact: ['user.email', 'user.password', 'user.hash'],
  });

What i get now:
[2024-04-11 16:34:44.563 +0200] ERROR (15036): 
Invalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    banned: false
  },
  select: {
?   id?: true,
?   email?: true,
?   profileUrl?: true,
?   avatar?: true,
?   firstName?: true,
?   lastName?: true,
?   hash?: true,
?   banned?: true,
?   confirmed?: true,
?   redirectUrl?: true,
?   sessions?: true,
?   teacherProfile?: true,
?   studentProfile?: true,
?   adminProfile?: true,
?   _count?: true
  },
  skip: 0,
  take: 10
}

The `select` statement for type User needs at least one truthy value.
    context: "UserService.findAllByFilter"

